# Взаимодействие со сторонними приложениями на Java

Tags: java, windows

Требуется, чтобы при запуске стороннего приложения на компьютере, допустим игры, моя Java программа выполняла определенный код. В связи с этим вопрос - как возможно реализовать обработчик события на открытие любого стороннего приложения?

Операционная система: Windows, x64

Comment: Нужно указать операционную систему. Приложения запускаются в ОС, и  решение будет зависеть от нее.

Comment: OS Windows, x64

Comment: Java не лучший язык для вашего случая. Весь API заточен под C так что будет не легко. К тому же сценарий который вы описали в основном используют вирусы, а операционные системы почему-то их не любят и стараются усложнить им жизнь.